# How are user interfaces for websites designed?

Tags: asp.net, user-interface

I am more of a server side programmer so bear with me on this. How exactly are user interfaces  for websites designed? I mean which tools are usually used? Lets say for example, stackoverflow.com which has lot of dynamic content. How are the various areas designed? I am pretty sure its not in Visual studio. Probably the server side code is in asp.net but what about the actual UI? (layout, images, tables, buttons etc)

What is the usual workflow for an activity like this? Say, I have a design on paper. Where do I go from there? How do you wire in the code after the interface design is complete?

How do you handle the fact that in a page, some of the stuff is static and some areas are dynamic? (like the ask question page I am on now)

Comment: It is *all* about Html/Css/JavaScript-jQuery.

Comment: This question is so difficult to answer because there is not one way to make it and requires experience on many fields.

Comment: @Aristos: I dont need to know how images and stuff like that are made. Lets narrow it down to a site like http://www.apple.com/. Not much of dynamic content. I want to know how the layout is achieved. How the shadows and bevel are implemented. Is it done in Photoshop and exported?

Answer (score 0):

The paper design is the first correct step.

How to continue:
You can get the 960 grid system from http://960.gs/  and start from this one. Its a nice trick that have ready to use css templates that you can build on them your design.

The image effects:
The shadow and borders and other thinks that you ask is usually make on Photoshop, but now the new browsers support many of them using css. For example: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Software that can help on design:
 - [MS Expression](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/)
 - [DreamWeaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html)

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me which software is actually used to lay it out all together in HTML?

Comment: @BobbyAlexander I use a simple text pad or the visual studio, I design what I won on html, then move it on aspx. The design software that you can use may be the : Visual Studio, MS expression studio, Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, It boils down to the requirement of the webpage.

For a professional (fairly big) website, many teams are involved for example, creative team to do the paper work and design of UI elements and controls, graphics team to actually design images, UI Developers for placing the contents appropriately and CSS, architects to decide on performance for various items (and taking a call on static/dynamic nature of controls)

Generally designers use some external tools for designing HTML pages to provide templates and same can be used later in visual studio to make actual pages. There are many such tools available in the market such as [Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html) There are many freeware also available in the market for designing client and CSS rich websites. You can search on Google for these.

If your website requirement is not very client rich, you can still design using visual studio or use new Microsoft product [Webmatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) which gives you user friendly tools to make a website look fabulous.